# react not rendering in chrome extension popup

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, render

I am having some trouble with my React App not rendering anything in my chrome extension popup.  Also, I am using Parcel as a webpacker to keep my files in the chrome extension format.

I used a template chrome extension for the popup and it worked with the template, but when I edited the files slightly it will no longer display.

My popup is just bank and non of the **index.js** 'App' is rendered.

index.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="NLP-title">NLP extension</h1>
        </header>
        <h2>Information regarding user info here:</h2>
        <body className="NLP-webpageinfo"> TEST </body>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.html snippet

```
<div id='root'></div>
```

manifest.json snippet

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "src/index.html"
  }
```

Any kind of help would be great.  I think I have some kind of syntax/mismatch somewhere in the **index.js**, but I am not too experienced with react development.

Comment: You need to load js files in your index.html (react and index). Note, the popup has its own devtools accessible via the rightclick menu "inspect".

Comment: load as in:
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/index.js"></script>
?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this package (even if you don't need to use redux, the setup will help you with the setup)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chrome-redux